# Trait not found in Laravale Custom Package

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I don't have an idea what I am doing wrong here...

I try to make a Laravel Package.

I created the folder packages

```
App
....
- packages
    -mine
        -mediaFiles
        -publicity
            -config
            -src
                PublicityServiceProvider.php
                -Traits
                    Publishable.php
                    Publicity.php
```

in my composer.json I have:

```
"psr-4": {
    "myapi\\": "app/",
    "Mine\\MediaFiles\\": "packages/mine/mediaFiles/src"
    "Mine\\Publicity\\": "packages/mine/publicity/src"
}
```

in the config/app.php i added

```
Mine\Publicity\PublicityServiceProvider::class,
```

and my Publicity.php

```
namespace Mine\Publicity\Traits;

trait Publicity
{
    public function test(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

my User Model:

```
use Mine\Publicity\Traits\Publicity;

class User extends Authenticatable

{
    use Fileable, Publicity;
```

I tried to use composer dump-autoload then but received an error during 'package:discover' ...

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Trait Mine\Publicity\Traits\Publicity not found
```

It also writes not found in User.php line 32 that's exactly where is 
    use Publicity;

I checked all the namespaces and filenames a few times, and now I don't have any idea what I am doing wrong here.

In the other package I made in this project, I did completely the same and it is working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Afterwards its showing the error.

Comment: Is there a missing comma in your composer.json or is that a pasting error?

Comment: The comma is there in my file, its a pasting error

Comment: Just taking stabs in the dark here, because everything *looks* correct. Maybe add `"Mine\\Publicity\\Traits\\": "packages/mine/publicity/src/Traits"` to your psr-4 autoload just to test. It seems odd that your `PublicityServiceProvider` is working fine though.

Comment: Didn't work as well. I started from the beginning with this package and now it's working - no idea what was the problem. Thanks anyway.